# move two paths in parallel in scala

Tags: scala, performance

I have two trees (paths), defined by a node like

```
trait Node {
  def getParent : Node
  def op(n:Node)
}
```

and I want to travel two nodes up until the parent is null in parallel like:

Pseudo:

```
def simultanousUp(/*var*/ a:Node,/*var*/ b:Node) = 
     while(a != null) {
          a.op(b); 
          a = a.getParent;
          b = if(b!=null) b.getParent else null /*or throw somthing*/;
      }
```

Question: is there a more elegant and/or performant way in scala to do this?

To avoid misunderstandings: its not a question about concurrent execution!

Comment: Since that pseudo doesn't work (no `var` in method arguments!), I'm not sure what you mean about "more elegant".

Comment: ^^ Thats one of the points ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@annotation.tailrec final def simultaneousUp(a: Node, b: Node) {
  if (a != null && b != null) {
    a op b
    simultaneousUp(a.getParent, b.getParent)
  }
  // Throw exception or whatever on mismatched lengths?
}
```

Comment: changed it slightly to  `simultaneousUp (a.getParent, if (b!=null) b.getParent else null)` in the tailrec. Thanks for this elegant solution!

Comment: @cybye - If `op` allows a `null` argument, probably also want to have only `(a != null)`.  Otherwise the change won't ever matter as you'll never be there with `b==null`.

Comment: yes, i changed that too but wanted keep the comment short. thanks again.

Comment: @jwinandy - It is not something you'd typically want, but it can be useful if performance is a major concern or if you need to interoperate with Java.  (At some point, it's better to just adopt a Java-like approach rather than pedantically wrapping everything with Option and then unwrapping.)  But I agree that this is not what one would call idiomatic code.

Comment: My idea on that is : If you need raw perf, you can code it in Java. There is a clear understanding of boxing, object birthing cost ...

Comment: @jwinandy - Why write twice as many type annotations as you need to, not have any operators, and be unable to express your intent as clearly with types when writing high-performance code?

Comment: Hum hum ! "If you were using types, why do you use null ? You could encode a bottom with a  proper algebraic datatype ..." I have a clear opinion on the subject, but well, it's my opinion and I shouldn't juge your practice. So let's stay there ;)

Comment: @jwinandy - `null` is already a perfectly sensible bottom type for `Node`.  Creating your own `NullNode` might be a good idea in C++ where dereferencing a null pointer is a disaster waiting to happen, but since it's just another exception for the JVM the only reason to do it is if you have significant use for a `NonNullNode` also, which is not the case in this example.

Comment: from my point of view, null is a tacit bottom for any type, so it's a bad bottom. Exceptions are bad in Scala and are also slow.

Comment: @jwinandy - You have failed to clearly express the alternative pattern.  There is one, but why not just state it instead of accusing `null` of being a bad bottom type?  Your type system already knows, for example, that you have a `Node`.  If it finds `null` there it's hardly going to matter that it could also be a bottom for `String`.

Comment: @RexKerr Sure I did fail to convince you (didn't plan to), let me try again : ```null``` IS an implicit bottom type and that's BAD FOR FORMAL METHODS. The type system knows nothing (really, nothing) about null, the runtime will find it, but the type system can't prevent you from using badly your API. That's also very bad from a documentation point of view. Again : I have a clear opinion on the subject, but well, it's my opinion and I shouldn't juge your practice. So let's stay there ;)

Comment: @jwinandy - What you're saying is not distinguishable from spouting dogma.  Adding a bottom type to `Node` is no more helpful than using `null`.  You should have pointed out that adding a superclass `NodeOption` with an empty type `NoNode` and a type with all the methods that require a node to actually exist, `Node` is helpful for type safety.  Otherwise you are just as able to try to use a method on `NoNode` that is not defined as you are to dereference `null`.  `null` and `NoNode <: Node` are algebraically _identical_ given that you know you have a `Node`.

Answer (score 3):

The parent cannot be null.

At first, let's be correct :

```
trait Node {
  def parent : Option[Node]
  def op(n:Node) // what does op mean ? what is the return type of op ? 
                 //cannot be Unit
}
```

then

```
@scala.annotation.tailrec 
//it makes sure it's tailrec, so it can be optimized
def simultanousUp(a:Node, b:Node): (Node,Node) = {
      a.op(b)
      (a.parent, b.parent) match {
          case (Some(pa), Some(pb)) => simultanousUp(pa,pb)
          case _ => (a,b)
      }

}
```

Comment: Safe but lower-performance.  Safety is probably more important.  Three object creations will take ~10-20 ns on most modern machines when the JVM's memory is not already heavily taxed.

Answer (score -1):

If op is a simple operation, you can't efficiently run it parallel, because traversing will consume significant time.

If op is a more complex (i.e. time consuming) operation, you can do it in parallel. However, you need to convert it to ParVector or something similar first.

---

I don't think there is a more performant way of traversing it. There is however a more elegant (but probably not so performant) solution by Stream:

```
def pathTo(start: Node): Stream[Node] = start.getParent match{
    case null => Stream.empty
    case nextPoint => Stream.cons(start, pathTo(nextPoint))
}
```

Comment: solve the problem of ancestor path, but since your nodes are mutables, you are lucky if it works.

Comment: So, you are traversing it while it is being mutated, aren't you?If so, you have to choose one state at which you perform the computation.